# Паралельный запуск тестов pytest

Tags: python, test-automation, непрерывная-интеграция, pytest

Встал вопрос о параллельном запуске тестов, например есть два набора тестов в разных фалах, нужно чтобы эти тесты наборы выполнялись параллельно. Куда копать не знаю, это все настраивается в самом тесте или в CI? Подскажите какие существуют практики?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для параллельного запуска тестов используй плагин [`pytest-xdist`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/), устанавливается как обычный пакет:

```
$ pip install pytest-xdist
```

Опция `-n/--numprocesses` задает количество процессов:

```
$ pytest -n8
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.10, pytest-5.3.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /tmp/foo
plugins: xdist-1.31.0, mock-1.11.0, asyncio-0.10.0, forked-1.0.2, cov-2.8.1, testinfra-3.2.0
gw0 [4] / gw1 [4] / gw2 [4] / gw3 [4] / gw4 [4] / gw5 [4] / gw6 [4] / gw7 [4]
....                                                                     [100%]
============================== 4 passed in 2.23s ===============================
```

> есть два набора тестов в разных файлах, нужно, чтобы эти тесты наборы выполнялись параллельно.

`xdist` поддерживает несколько типов планировщиков:

- `load` (по умолчанию): каждый тест выполняется в отдельном воркере
- `loadscope`: тесты-функции из одного файла выполняются в одном воркере, тесты-методы из одного тесткласса выполняются в одном воркере
- `loadfile`: тесты из одного файла выполняются в одном воркере
- `each`: весь набор тестов прогоняется в каждом воркере отдельно, т.е. как если бы прогон тестов выполнялся параллельно в нескольких терминалах сразу.

Поэтому запускай `pytest --dist=loadfile`.

> это все настраивается в самом тесте или в CI?

В самом тесте это не настраивается, но можно вынести опции в файл конфигурации `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --dist=loadfile
```